# How to Left Join 2 tables where 2 fields match

Tags: mysql, datatable, left-join

I want to transfer the data from
 `cms_nodeinfo.description` 
TO 
`wp_postmeta.meta_value` 
**ONLY IF** the `cms_nodeinfo.nodeid **MATCHES** wp_postmeta.post_id` 
**AND** if the `wp_postmeta.meta_key **EQUALS** '_yoast_wpseo_metadesc'`

Here's an example of a query I tried:

```
SELECT
    cms_nodeinfo.description, wp_postmeta.meta_value
FROM
    cms_nodeinfo, wp_postmeta
WHERE
    cms_nodeinfo.nodeid = wp_postmeta.post_id
    wp_postmeta.meta_key = _yoast_wpseo_metadesc
```

ps. Guys, I'm NOT a coder, I'm learning as I go, please be patient with me. Thank you.

Okay, like this, I think, but I need help with the actual syntax that I could paste into the query:

```
SELECT cms_nodeinfo.description 
FROM cms_nodeinfo 
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta ON cms_nodeinfo.description = wp_postmeta.meta_value 
WHERE wp_postmeta.meta_key = _yoast_wpseo_metadesc AND cms_nodeinfo.nodeid = wp_postmeta.post_id
```

I also tried

```
SELECT
   cms_nodeinfo.description
FROM
   cms_nodeinfo
LEFT JOIN cms_nodeinfo.description ON
   wp_postmeta.meta_value
WHERE
   wp_postmeta.meta_key = _yoast_wpseo_metadesc AND cms_nodeinfo.nodeid = wp_postmeta.post_id
```

but that returned an error saying that

```
Table 'cms_nodeinfo.description' doesn't exist
```

The table names are cms_nodeinfo and wp_postmeta. The goal is to have the description field from the cms_nodeinfo transfer into the meta_value field of the wp_postmeta table.

I also tried:

```
SELECT
    `description`
FROM
    cms_nodeinfo
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta.meta_value WHERE // LINE 5
    wp_postmeta.meta_key = _yoast_wpseo_metadesc AND cms_nodeinfo.nodeid = wp_postmeta.post_id
```

but that returns the following error:

```
 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE
    wp_postmeta.meta_key = _yoast_wpseo_metadesc AND cms_nodeinfo.nodeid ' at line 5
```

I also tried:

```
SELECT
    `description`
FROM
    cms_nodeinfo
WHERE
    wp_postmeta.meta_key = `_yoast_wpseo_metadesc` AND cms_nodeinfo.nodeid = wp_postmeta.post_id
LEFT JOIN cms_nodeinfo.description ON //LINE7
    wp_postmeta.meta_value


but that returns:
 check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'LEFT JOIN cms_nodeinfo.description ON
    wp_postmeta.meta_value LIMIT 0, 25' at line 7 (marked)
```

I also tried:

```
SELECT `cms_nodeinfo`.`description`, `wp_postmeta`.`meta_key`, `cms_nodeinfo`.`nodeid`
FROM `cms_nodeinfo`, `wp_postmeta`
LEFT JOIN `wp_postmeta`.`meta_value`
WHERE `wp_postmeta`.`meta_key` = '_yoast_wpseo_metadesc' AND `cms_nodeinfo`.`nodeid` = `wp_postmeta`.`post_id`;  //LINE4


which returns a syntax error in line 4 (marked)
```

I've also tried:

```
SELECT
    `cms_nodeinfo`.`description`,
    `wp_postmeta`.`meta_key`,
    `cms_nodeinfo`.`nodeid`
FROM
    `cms_nodeinfo`,
    `wp_postmeta`
LEFT JOIN `cms_nodeinfo.description`
  ON `wp_postmeta`.`meta_value` 
 WHERE
    `wp_postmeta`.`meta_key` = '_yoast_wpseo_metadesc' AND `cms_nodeinfo`.`nodeid` = `wp_postmeta`.`post_id`;
```

I also tried:

```
REPLACE `meta_value` WITH `cms_nodeinfo`.`description`, WHERE `wp_postmeta`.`meta_key` = '_yoast_wpseo_metadesc' AND `cms_nodeinfo`.`nodeid` = `wp_postmeta`.`post_id`;
```

@Martin Suggested:

> FROM tbl LEFT JOIN x ON x.a = tbl.a AND x.b = tbl.b

So I tried that here:

```
FROM                 //POSITION 0
    `cms_nodeinfo`,
LEFT JOIN `cms_nodeinfo.description`
ON `wp_postmeta`.`meta_value` 
 WHERE
    `wp_postmeta`.`meta_key` = '_yoast_wpseo_metadesc' AND `cms_nodeinfo`.`nodeid` = `wp_postmeta`.`post_id`;


which returned the error:
Unrecognized statement type. (near "FROM" at position 0)
```

Maybe I'm using the wrong type of join? I tried INNER JOIN too and that didn't work either.

```
SELECT
    `cms_nodeinfo`.`description`,
    `wp_postmeta`.`meta_key`,
    `cms_nodeinfo`.`nodeid`
FROM
    `cms_nodeinfo`,
    `wp_postmeta`
INNER JOIN `wp_postmeta`.`meta_value` WHERE
    `wp_postmeta`.`meta_key` = '_yoast_wpseo_metadesc' AND `cms_nodeinfo`.`nodeid` = `wp_postmeta`.`post_id`;
```

Okay, this one successfully runs but no data is returned

```
SELECT
    `cms_nodeinfo`.`description`
FROM
    `cms_nodeinfo`
LEFT JOIN `wp_postmeta` ON `wp_postmeta`.`meta_value` = `cms_nodeinfo`.`description`
WHERE
    `wp_postmeta`.`meta_key` = '_yoast_wpseo_metadesc' AND `cms_nodeinfo`.`nodeid` = `wp_postmeta`.`post_id`;
```

I've also tried RIGHT Join, INNER and FULL, all of which fail. The field is there, but I can't get the data to populate into it.

**Any ideas?? Help, please?!**

Comment: You can use multiple criteria on any join, so you can do something like `FROM tbl LEFT JOIN x ON x.a = tbl.a AND x.b = tbl.b`.  Try to have a go at the query yourself and update your question with your attempt

Comment: Are there any matching values between `wp_postmeta.meta_value` and `cms_nodeinfo.description`? You can check it by removing the whole WHERE statement from your last query.

Comment: @forpas (Thank you for your reply!) Yes. there are several thousand. But I only want to insert the contents of the cms_nodeinfo.description into the wp_postmeta.meta_value the cms_nodeinfo.nodeid matches the wp_postmeta.post_id  AND wp_postmeta.meta_key` = '_yoast_wpseo_metadesc'

Comment: So you have a really long question and still you have not clarified what you exactly want. It's time to edit your question and explain. Post the table's create statements as well as sample data and expected results.

Comment: I want to transfer the data from     cms_nodeinfo.description     TO 
    wp_postmeta.meta_value     ONLY IF the     cms_nodeinfo.nodeid     MATCHES     wp_postmeta.post_id     AND if the      wp_postmeta.meta_key     EQUALS     '_yoast_wpseo_metadesc'

Comment: *transfer the data* do you mean update the column `meta_value` of the table `wp_postmeta`?

Comment: yes, with the data that's in `cms_nodeinfo.description`  (IF the other 2 conditions are also met)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update under the conditions you set with this:

```
update 
  wp_postmeta inner join cms_nodeinfo
  on cms_nodeinfo.nodeid = wp_postmeta.post_id
set
  wp_postmeta.meta_value = cms_nodeinfo.description
where wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_yoast_wpseo_metadesc'
```